# React.JS: Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I converted the code into react-table and now getting this error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I don't see the infinite loop in my code, can anyone help?

```
// core packages
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

// local imports
import useCustomTable from '../../../utils/hooks/useTable';
import TableFooter from '../../components/table-footer/TableFooter';
import { ROWS_PER_PAGE } from '../../../utils/constants';
import { formatJsonString } from '../../../utils/helpers/helpers';
import PopupButton from '../../components/popup-button/PopupButton';
import { actions as productOrderActions } from '../../../store/productOrder';
import { selectProductOrder } from 'store/productOrder/selector';

// styles
import './SearchResults.css';

const serviceNameMap = val => (
  <tr key={val.serviceName + val.serviceAction + 'N'}>
    <td className="s1">{val.serviceName}</td>
  </tr>
);

const serviceActionMap = val => (
  <tr key={val.serviceName + val.serviceAction + 'A'}>
    <td className="s2">{val.serviceAction}</td>
  </tr>
);

const serviceDueDateMap = val => (
  <tr key={val.serviceName + val.serviceAction + 'D'}>
    <td className="s3">
      {String(val.dueDate).substring(0, 10) === 'null'
        ? ''
        : String(val.dueDate).substring(0, 10)}
    </td>
  </tr>
);

const SearchResults = ( props ) => {

  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const isDict = dict => {
    return typeof dict === 'object' && !Array.isArray(dict);
  };

  const [resDict, setResDict] = useState({});
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const { slice, range } = useCustomTable(
    isDict(props.response) ? [props.response] : props.response,
    page,
    ROWS_PER_PAGE,
  );

  const [productOrder, setProductOrder] = useState({ payload: '{}' });
  const selectedProductOrder = useSelector(selectProductOrder);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProductOrder(selectedProductOrder);
  }, [selectedProductOrder]);

  const data = slice.map(val => {
    const len = val.orderDetails.length;
    const versionNames = [];
    for (let i = len; i > 0; i--) {
      versionNames.push(i);
    }
    const order = val.orderDetails[resDict[val.hoi] || 0];
    return {
      hoi: order.hoi,
      orderSystem: order.orderSystem,
      brand: order.brand,
      status: order.status,
      serviceName: (<table cellSpacing="0">
                      <tbody>
                        {order.serviceDetails.map(val => serviceNameMap(val))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>),
      serviceAction: (<table cellSpacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                          {order.serviceDetails.map(val => serviceActionMap(val))}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>),
      serviceDueDate: (<table cellSpacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                          {order.serviceDetails.map(val => serviceDueDateMap(val))}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>),
      provisioning: order.provisioning,
      billing: order.billing,
      shipping: order.shipping,
      createDate: order.initialVersionCreateDate.substring(0, 10) +
                  '\n' +
                  order.initialVersionCreateDate.substring(11, 19),
      lastModified: order.currentVersionCreateDate.substring(0, 10) +
                    '\n' +
                    order.currentVersionCreateDate.substring(11, 19),
      version: (
        <select className="version verSp" name="version"
          onChange={event => setResDict(() => ({ [order.hoi]: len - event.target.value }))} >
          {versionNames.map(versionName => (
            <option name={versionName} key={versionName} value={versionName} >
              {versionName}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      ),
      productOrder: (
        <PopupButton
          onClick={() =>dispatch(productOrderActions.loadProductOrder({ENV: props.env, ORDER_NUMBER: order.hoi}))}
          buttonName={t('search_results.product_order')}
          title={t('search_results.product_order') + ': ' + order.hoi}
          content={formatJsonString(productOrder?.payload)}
        />
      ),
      moreInfo: (
        <button
          className="Button-Active"
          onClick={() =>
            navigate('/orderInsightDetails', {
              state: { version: order.version, env: props.env, orderID: order.hoi },
            })
          }
        >
          {t('search_results.more_info')}
        </button>
      ),
    };
  });

  const columns = React.useMemo(() => [
      {
        Header: t('search_results.hoi'),
        accessor: 'hoi',
        className: 'id',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.order_system'),
        accessor: 'orderSystem',
        className: 'orderSystem',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.brand'),
        accessor: 'brand',
        className: 'brand',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.status'),
        accessor: 'status',
        className: 'status',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.provisioning'),
        accessor: 'serviceName',
        className: 'serviceName',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.billing'),
        accessor: 'serviceAction',
        className: 'serviceAction',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.shipping'),
        accessor: 'serviceDueDate',
        className: 'serviceDueDate',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.provisioning'),
        accessor: 'provisioning',
        className: 'provisioning',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.billing'),
        accessor: 'billing',
        className: 'billing',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.shipping'),
        accessor: 'shipping',
        className: 'shipping',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.create_date'),
        accessor: 'createDate',
        className: 'createDate',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.last_modified'),
        accessor: 'lastModified',
        className: 'versionDate',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.version'),
        accessor: 'version',
        className: 'version',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.latest_product_order'),
        accessor: 'productOrder',
        className: 'info',
      },
      {
        Header: t('search_results.more_info'),
        accessor: 'moreInfo',
        className: 'info',
      },
    ]
  );

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({ columns, data });

  return (
    <>
    {isDict(props.response) ? navigate('/notfoundpage')
      : 
      <>
        <div className='scrollWrap'>
          <table {...getTableProps()} className='outerTable' cellSpacing='0'>
            <thead>
              {headerGroups?.map(headerGroup => (
                <tr {...headerGroup?.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                  {headerGroup?.headers?.map(column => (
                    <th {...column?.getHeaderProps()}>{column?.render('Header')}</th>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {rows?.map(row => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                  <tr {...row?.getRowProps()} className='mainRow'>
                    {row?.cells?.map(cell => (
                      <td className={cell.column.className} {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                        {cell.render('Cell')}
                      </td>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <TableFooter range={range} page={page} setPage={setPage}></TableFooter>
      </>
    }
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchResults;
```

I tried deleting useState() statements and also tried deleting all the code which contains onClick() and onChange() events. I also tried with only single valued columns like hoi, orderSystem, brand and status but the issue is still there.

Comment: I would suggest commenting out big portions of this component until you can narrow down which bit is causing the error, this is quite a large chunk of code for us to try and debug with basically no context.

Comment: Can you comment out **useEffect** and try again.

Comment: You need to wrap `data` (as in the whole `slice.map(val => {` and everything related therein) in a `useMemo`